# How to create a WORD ENLISTER PROGRAM

Tags: java, arrays

I'm only starting at java as a student. I don't know how to input the words in a sentence in an array. I'm confused and lost on how to separate each words in a sentence. I already have the algorithm to check vowels and consonants with their counts. How do I do the array? I'm really lost.

```
 String[] array = new String[];


 out.print("Enter a phrase/sentence: ");

for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = scan.nextLine();
}


out.print(">>Words Enlisted: ");
System.out.println(array[2]);
```

Enter a phrase/sentence: The apple, banana, and chico are fruits

```
>> Words Enlisted:
 [1] THE
 – 3 Letter(s)
 - 2 Consonant(s): T H
 - 1 Vowel(s): E
 [2] APPLE
 – 5 Letter(s)
 - 3 Consonant(s): P P L
 - 1 Vowel(s): A E
 [3] BANANA
 – 6 Letter(s)
 - 3 Consonant(s): B N N
 - 3 Vowel(s): A A A
```

Comment: You mean splitting a string?

Comment: yes. and scanning the, or something

Comment: Do you want to put each word in an element of array and check the consonants and vowels for every element in array? (This is what I understood)

Comment: The `String` object has a `Split` method - not sure if the assignment permits you to use that, or if the professor wants you to write one. Either way, you probably want to split on spaces (to get the distinct words) and then strip off any punctuation.

Comment: If you can't use split the other method is to use `scanner` and `next();`. `For next();` the default delimiter is white space. The only thing you need to worry is punctuation which can be removed with the help of regex

Comment: Exactly @Goion please teach me

Answer (score 3):

This creates an array of the inputted sentence. I am using the example you used as an example here:

```
String sentence = "The apple, banana, and chico are fruits";
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
The
apple,
banana,
and
chico
are
fruits
```